# change focus into particular div

Tags: jquery

how can i change focus into particular div after any event via jquery?

Comment: Well you can use: `$('#element').focus()` but i'm not too sure what you mean, because this won't have any effect on DIVs. You can't "focus" a div really... it doesn't do anything. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To make a div focusable, it needs to have a [`tabindex`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) attribute.

```
<div id='test' tabindex='1'></div>
```

Then, you can focus with e.g.

```
$('#something').click(function() {
  $('#test').focus();
});
```

Comment: It is fine with IE and Chrome.It is not working in Firefox.What can i do?

Comment: [This data](http://nemisj.com/focusable/) seems to indicate it should work in FF. Are you sure it's just not a display issue?

Comment: @Loganphp - I tested Firefox 3.6.8 using [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SNXk2/) and it worked fine.

Comment: ya fine.Your example is working me also but i don't know why mine is not working

Comment: tabindex to focus on non form elements, cool! Never new, thank you!

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I've been looking for this solution for a long time. Appreciated.

Comment: yes it work. to get more clarification visit http://vijaylathiya.blogspot.in/2014/04/move-cursor-focus-to-div-element-using.html

Comment: You should use `tabindex="0"` otherwise your element would be the first thing tabbed to on a keyboard.

Comment: what if you want one action to focus on one div and a second action to focus on a different div?   put tabindex=0 for both and it will go to correct one based on id?

Answer (score 11):

Use `$(window).scrollTop()` It'll scroll the window to the particular item.

Here is the example

```
 var scrollPos =  $(".focusme").offset().top;
 $(window).scrollTop(scrollPos);
```

Comment: nice one.  Any idea how to calculate the window size and subtract 45% of that amount so the scroll pos ends up somewhere in the centre?

Comment: found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952533/jquery-position-div-in-middle-of-page#answer-4952569) :)