# jQuery position div in middle of page

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, so I have a div and I want to position it in the middle of a page.
I've gotten so far

```
$("#a").css('margin-top', '(document).height()/2 - ("#a").height()/2');
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It shouldn't be in quotes. Also, you need to use the `$()` terminology. Try this:

```
$("#a").css('margin-top', $(document).height()/2 - $("#a").height()/2);
```

Or even better:

```
var $a = $("#a");
$a.css('margin-top', $(document).height()/2 - $a.height()/2);
```

**Edit:** Just to be clear, you can't put it in quotes because it will try to set the margin-top property literally to that string. Which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes... It works! Thanks. I never knew it was as simple as removing the quotes.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset#offset2).

**Description:** Set the current coordinates of every element in the set of matched elements, *relative* to the *document*.

```
$("#a").offset({
   top: $(document).height()/2 -  $("#a").height()/2,
   left: $(document).width()/2 -  $("#a").width()/2
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me & might help:

```
$('html, body').animate(
   {
   scrollTop: $('#your_div_id').offset().top-200
   }, 1000);
```

Change value 200 in **'top-200'** to position your div as per your need..