# How to focus div?

Tags: jquery, html

Please don't throw stones at me because i'm total newbie at js and jquery.
is it possible to focus a div?
i just wanted to process events when div is clicked OR is focused and when we click outside the div. Something like that:

HTML:

```
<div id="focusedDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
    $("#focusedDiv").focus(function () {
        ....
    });

    $("#focusedDiv").focusout(function () {
        ....        
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3777600/1763929

Comment: Refer this Link ,I think this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to set tabindex attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/QAkGV/

```
<div id="focusedDiv" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Or:

```
$("#focusedDiv").attr('tabindex',-1).focus(function () {
        ....
    });
```

For style, you could set outline CSS property too:

```
$("#focusedDiv").css('outline',0).attr('tabindex',-1).focus(function () {
        ....
    });
```

Comment: yes to focus on Div element 1st you need to set tabindex property -1 than it  jQuery .focus work look at http://vijaylathiya.blogspot.in/2014/04/move-cursor-focus-to-div-element-using.html