# ng-blur on a DIV

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, blur

I am trying to hide a `DIV` on blur (the focus has been removed from the `DIV`).  I am using angular and bootstrap.  So far I have tried setting "focus" on the `DIV` when it is shown and then an `ng-blur` function when the user click anywhere else on the screen.  This is not working.

Basically the problem is I cannot set focus on my "`#lockerBox`" through JS, my "`hideLocker`" function works no problem when focus is given to my `DIV` with clicking it.

```
<div class="lock-icon" ng-click="showLocker(result); $event.stopPropagation();"></div>
<div ng-show="result.displayLocker" id="lockerBox" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" ng-blur="hideLocker(result)" tabindex="1">

  $scope.displayLocker = false;
  $scope.showLocker = function ( result ) {

    $scope.displayLocker = !$scope.displayLocker;
    node.displayLocker = $scope.displayLocker;

    function setFocus() {
      angular.element( document.querySelector( '#lockerBox' ) ).addClass('focus');
    }

    $timeout(setFocus, 100);
  };


  $scope.hideLocker = function ( node ) {
    $scope.displayLocker = false;
    node.displayLocker = $scope.displayLocker;
  };
```

Comment: Did you try passing $event to your hideLocker and then calling $event.target.focus()? Also I would get rid of the stopPropagation business unless you really need it.

Comment: No, the target could be any other element on the screen. I need the focus set in the 'showLocker' function.  And the element that is the target of that event is another DIV unrelated to the DIV I need to give focus to.

Comment: What about ng-focus and a property on your view model? If you can get ng-focus on the right element then all you have to do is modify your model.

Comment: why are you using focus and blur on `div` elements that aren't contenteditable? What is objective?

Answer (score 24):

Just add `tabindex="-1"` attr to the `div` and it gives it the same behave like an input  -

```
<div tabindex="-1" ng-blur="onBlur()"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ast12nLf/1/

(Inspired from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17042452/831294)

Comment: tabindex-1 means [here](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex) A tabindex="-1" value removes the element from the default navigation flow (i.e., a user cannot tab to it), but it allows it to receive programmatic focus, meaning focus can be set to it from a link or with scripting.** This can be very useful for elements that should not be tabbed to, but that may need to have focus set to them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just setting the blur event on the element that has the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem - but was able to resolve it using 'mouseup' event on the entire document in a custom directive following is the code,
where I am toggling an accordion contained in a div as pop-up using ng-show()="variable"
now this variable is the key here across menu toggle button HTML Element, div pop up HTML Element, and the custom directive to handle mouse up!

```js
var dummyDirective = angular.module(dummyDirective, []);
dummyDirective.directive('hideOnMouseUpElsewhere', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var container = $(element);

        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
          && container.has(e.target).length === 0 && scope.status.menuVisible // ... nor a descendant of the container
          && !(e.target.id === attr.excludeClick)) // do not execute when clicked on this 
        {
          scope.status.menuVisible = false;
          scope.$apply();
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

where container will have the DOM element you applied 'hideOnMouseUpElsewhere' directive on along with added attribute 'excludeClick' and e.target is the one DOM element where you click

Following is the HTML code for a accrodian bootstrap angular popup menu:

```html
<a id="MenuAnchor" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="status.menuVisible = !status.menuVisible;">
  <i id= "MenuIcon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="font-size:20px; color: #428bca; cursor:pointer;"></i>
</a>
<div  id ="MenuPane"  ng-blur="status.menuVisible=false;" hide-on-mouse-up-elsewhere exclude-click='MenuIcon'>
 <div class="btn-group favoritesMenu" style="width: 300px;" ng-show="status.menuVisible"  >
 <accordion close-others="true">
  <accordion-group > 
    <accordion-heading>....</accordion-heading>
    <div ng-click="status.menuVisible=false;">Data</div>
  </accordion-group> 
 </accordion>
```