# How to focus scrollable elements like mouse click without "tabindex" in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm creating an keyboard navigation extension which need to focus an scrollable element to scroll it for Google Chrome. Because this is just an extension, so I want not to edit existing DOMs like [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777580/change-focus-into-particular-div).

I want to focus an element like "mouse click to a scrollable element". Mouse click to an scrollable element, and then you can scroll the element by arrow keys. This has the following feature:

- No focus visual effect

  - "`tabindex` hack" change the element like a focused textarea border.
- No change `document.activeElement`
- No change attributes

I read some similar OSS sources like vinium, but these are scrolling by javascript, or do nothing for scrollable elements. So I think there seems to be no way.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid making DOM changes? A lot of extensions edit the DOM of the page. And adding tabindex="0" to an element is a very safe change to make

Comment: I do not really want to realize it. I want to know it if the way exists. I think it is  better to change visual less like listed features.