# tabindex attribute on div did not solve focus

Tags: jquery

> This is **not** a duplicate question. Clearly, I've come to ask this question because the other suggested questions did not fulfill the needs specific to this question. *That, or I'm missing something here* Edit: I was clearly missing something/(s) .  This is, now, [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44181969/5040900).

---

### What I want

I want to scroll up to the div with `id='focus-message'` when the AJAX request is called as it rewrites the HTML.

### Problem

Unfortunately, I can't even get the focus to land on the div normally, even without AJAX. This is not working even without AJAX

### What I tried

I referred to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777600/5040900) , according to which, div needs a `tabindex` attribute in order to focus. I set the attribute value to 1  like so, `tabindex='1'` but it just won't work, to my frustration.

I referred to several other answers, amongst which I [liked this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551414/5040900). But to my dismay, it is not compatible with my needs. My div can be anywhere(top of bottom after the AJAX call) so I think I need focus(*unless I'm mistaken; please feel free to correct me.*).

### Here's a Snippet

When it is run, I want the div with `id='focus-message'` to be focused. Am I asking the wrong questions? What am I missing? Where did I go wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("focus-message").focus;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Nam in justo eros. Praesent blandit venenatis sollicitudin. Donec vitae laoreet sem, at aliquam ligula. Morbi aliquet congue augue, ut vehicula neque semper quis. Fusce est ante, pellentesque a sollicitudin non, egestas ut dolor. In sit amet lorem vitae
  tellus mollis lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Duis cursus consectetur enim et dapibus. Suspendisse urna justo, placerat finibus venenatis et, mattis at odio. Aliquam pellentesque, sem gravida convallis ornare, libero sapien blandit turpis, ut laoreet
  sapien mi ut lorem. Vestibulum ornare sit amet tellus sit amet aliquet. Curabitur mauris sapien, vestibulum ac auctor ut, consequat vel massa. Vivamus sit amet mauris fermentum, laoreet sapien in, mattis elit. In tincidunt, mi at ullamcorper lacinia,
  lectus tellus convallis felis, sit amet ultrices sapien nisi volutpat quam. Sed nec odio lacinia, tempor ligula at, ullamcorper ante. Phasellus eget vulputate purus.
</p>

<p>
  Nulla facilisi. Sed molestie lacus non ex ultricies, gravida gravida tortor porta. Nullam sed magna sed justo congue posuere commodo ut massa. Aliquam rhoncus nunc nulla, vitae commodo urna laoreet porta. Pellentesque eu tellus faucibus, rhoncus nunc
  sit amet, congue lectus. Praesent consectetur est nisi, finibus porttitor eros euismod ac. Integer ac magna a erat eleifend tempus. Quisque nec neque ullamcorper, volutpat est finibus, laoreet magna. Integer sit amet sodales justo. Sed accumsan dolor
  augue, at faucibus turpis pulvinar ac. Etiam sed lorem ligula.
</p>

<p>
  Quisque lobortis mattis nunc, mattis rutrum nisi sodales a. In iaculis consequat mauris, ac vulputate enim volutpat eget. Morbi vel nulla suscipit, fermentum leo id, sollicitudin quam. Etiam tincidunt libero turpis, ut consequat lorem consequat a. Nulla
  quam odio, molestie quis mauris eget, eleifend rhoncus nisi. Pellentesque vel vulputate nulla. Curabitur volutpat risus et felis facilisis venenatis. Sed at interdum nibh. Praesent rhoncus neque eros, quis placerat tellus laoreet vitae. Aliquam feugiat
  non ante quis porttitor. Duis eu libero cursus, molestie elit a, accumsan tellus. Ut in tincidunt metus, a aliquet magna. Nam vitae tellus sit amet erat varius suscipit. Integer dapibus consequat risus, a facilisis ex sodales ac.
</p>

<p>
  Integer sed ornare velit, ut maximus orci. Aliquam pellentesque nisl in lorem mollis ullamcorper. Mauris ullamcorper metus nec rhoncus laoreet. Proin dui ex, laoreet id sem at, hendrerit ornare magna. In varius dolor quis nibh semper gravida. Etiam ut
  magna ut ante blandit convallis et id nulla. Praesent sagittis nunc sit amet nunc tempor sagittis. Sed at sapien vitae neque rhoncus pretium. Morbi ultrices, ex id tincidunt placerat, ante arcu semper neque, vel consequat velit tellus eu leo. Nam convallis
  lorem fermentum auctor vestibulum.
</p>

<p>
  Morbi ac ante purus. In hendrerit commodo interdum. Mauris nec libero condimentum, pharetra nunc ac, viverra velit. Sed consequat erat sit amet ex aliquet semper. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc blandit neque eget mi faucibus, non placerat sapien mollis. Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent et massa sollicitudin, posuere velit vitae, convallis urna. In id turpis tellus. Nullam ligula mauris, blandit id facilisis in, hendrerit a sem. Vestibulum sodales vulputate est, non finibus
  quam scelerisque quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce sagittis dapibus eros, a finibus nunc vulputate vel. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
  ac turpis egestas.
</p>

<p>
  Duis ullamcorper justo et nulla placerat iaculis. Nunc dictum felis pulvinar tortor eleifend ullamcorper. Aliquam pretium, ipsum quis porttitor cursus, dolor dolor tincidunt libero, in tincidunt enim sem vitae dolor. Etiam ex mauris, ullamcorper a blandit
  in, placerat a orci. Curabitur purus ex, placerat eu condimentum a, interdum at diam. Donec dignissim nisl eget sapien blandit, molestie hendrerit tellus tristique. Fusce consectetur nisl pellentesque ullamcorper tincidunt. Ut pharetra eget nunc non
  consectetur. Curabitur consequat ut elit consequat consequat. Fusce imperdiet dui augue, ut lobortis mi consequat quis. Nulla tincidunt aliquet urna quis tempus. Integer sagittis magna sed maximus dapibus. Nam orci arcu, feugiat efficitur scelerisque
  et, pretium id sapien. Vestibulum finibus ultricies neque eget ultrices. Duis ornare leo condimentum felis iaculis, sit amet condimentum tortor feugiat. Quisque efficitur eros sem, ac consequat arcu placerat sit amet.
</p>

<p>
  Pellentesque arcu eros, aliquet a viverra ut, egestas a elit. Nulla lorem magna, volutpat vel consequat sed, ornare ut erat. Integer ullamcorper, sem et maximus sodales, sapien purus tempus quam, vel faucibus dolor risus viverra nulla. Integer suscipit
  arcu a nulla faucibus pellentesque. Donec id eleifend augue. Donec id luctus ante, non dapibus libero. Donec enim odio, mollis et rutrum sed, semper id tortor. Duis sed lacus felis. Sed dictum pulvinar orci in faucibus. Phasellus non varius erat, quis
  facilisis dui. Fusce non nunc ac lectus interdum consectetur. Nunc in suscipit mi. Aliquam interdum sapien non purus malesuada laoreet. Vestibulum a diam nec sapien commodo aliquam. Sed eget accumsan justo, consequat suscipit mauris.
</p>

<p>
  In finibus vel mi ac feugiat. In efficitur fermentum metus, vel porta massa molestie non. Ut vitae tortor ut urna dapibus fringilla. Nullam ornare placerat bibendum. Suspendisse et venenatis nisi. Cras tincidunt placerat erat id volutpat. Nunc sed eros
  eu lacus pulvinar bibendum vel id augue. Proin id lorem augue.
</p>

<p>
  Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In non est ullamcorper, congue ante non, mollis purus. Donec cursus posuere sagittis. Fusce rutrum vitae orci ut mollis. Nunc elementum lectus eu placerat vehicula. Morbi vitae efficitur libero.
  Vivamus suscipit malesuada erat ac tempor. Nulla ullamcorper tellus id hendrerit ullamcorper. Ut tellus nisl, tempus viverra porta in, vulputate non augue. Morbi aliquet neque eu neque scelerisque egestas. Nulla porta, leo nec ultricies hendrerit, lacus
  neque porttitor lorem, sed viverra erat purus vel est. Ut a purus et eros porttitor pellentesque. Donec ut ligula ornare lorem viverra condimentum ac feugiat ligula.
</p>

<p>
  Nulla purus metus, molestie vel ligula ut, ultricies tristique urna. Sed gravida nisi id iaculis porttitor. Sed id orci in ligula varius malesuada eu a enim. Proin ullamcorper sagittis imperdiet. Donec quis sodales tellus. Quisque volutpat ipsum quis
  accumsan tempor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris tempor efficitur risus, non rutrum ex aliquet ac.
</p>

<p>
  Aliquam arcu odio, tristique sit amet ex at, consequat suscipit dolor. Nunc efficitur mauris sit amet porttitor pellentesque. Aliquam auctor lorem eget mi laoreet tristique. Cras eros risus, dapibus non vestibulum eget, consectetur in est. Cras congue
  et justo quis varius. Morbi rhoncus condimentum dui, eget dapibus metus interdum id. Proin feugiat ligula vitae nulla porta porttitor. Donec sit amet vestibulum urna. Phasellus ornare ullamcorper lectus vitae aliquet. Nunc imperdiet turpis sapien, tristique
  accumsan tortor dignissim eu. Nunc dictum purus eu massa maximus fermentum. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper eros. Nullam in urna et ex aliquam tincidunt.
</p>

<p>
  Proin faucibus condimentum eleifend. Suspendisse sed felis nec nisl convallis eleifend. Ut a lorem et mi dignissim accumsan in in magna. Nulla eget consequat mauris. Phasellus odio ex, tincidunt non elit ac, commodo mollis quam. Etiam tempor sem ut nunc
  faucibus molestie. Mauris commodo mauris mi, at dapibus neque consectetur sed.
</p>

<p>
  Vivamus at lobortis augue, quis accumsan ex. Phasellus nec pulvinar eros, at consectetur urna. Fusce id lacinia dolor. Curabitur auctor metus dui, non fringilla mauris consectetur nec. Nulla aliquam orci et pretium euismod. Curabitur tristique consectetur
  finibus. Pellentesque condimentum sodales aliquet. Etiam augue augue, faucibus sed congue eu, volutpat elementum nunc. Donec imperdiet arcu vestibulum felis dignissim, at pretium leo volutpat. Quisque gravida purus nisl, sed pulvinar metus commodo quis.
</p>

<p>
  Morbi aliquet cursus elit, nec fermentum diam. Donec tortor nisl, gravida a lobortis nec, dictum sit amet elit. Nunc rhoncus sem a aliquet suscipit. Duis erat sem, efficitur volutpat facilisis non, aliquet vitae tellus. Sed ex elit, ullamcorper a dolor
  quis, mollis sodales dolor. Aenean bibendum leo augue, a pretium ante maximus nec. Phasellus nec risus at nisi laoreet hendrerit nec eu tellus. Phasellus euismod sollicitudin est vel ultricies. Cras suscipit elit orci.
</p>

<p>
  Nam quis dui aliquam, rutrum dolor id, commodo nisi. Mauris interdum eros ac odio pharetra efficitur sed et turpis. Quisque vitae erat orci. Sed ornare ultricies molestie. In gravida porta quam, ut iaculis nisl venenatis at. Sed elementum auctor suscipit.
  Vestibulum rutrum, lorem eu tristique suscipit, felis felis varius arcu, a vestibulum dolor mauris ut velit. Integer placerat urna id mauris sodales, mollis scelerisque felis consectetur. Proin fringilla lacus at molestie fringilla. Morbi vitae porta
  mauris. In ut leo ut metus pulvinar finibus. Pellentesque id mi quis enim porta interdum. Aliquam vulputate tristique lobortis. Vestibulum sollicitudin rhoncus nunc quis rhoncus.
</p>

<p>
  Etiam et enim rhoncus, euismod elit in, facilisis diam. Nulla vehicula dui nec ultrices vestibulum. Pellentesque tristique, mauris a euismod convallis, massa libero luctus massa, eu elementum enim mi quis lacus. Duis non sapien eget lectus pulvinar fringilla
  eu sit amet nibh. Nam porta lectus at nisl imperdiet ornare. Mauris eget quam interdum, congue magna nec, semper augue. Fusce erat orci, fermentum ut turpis sit amet, gravida blandit purus. Duis vel posuere lectus, id finibus neque. Fusce nec molestie
  odio, id rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt lectus ipsum, nec malesuada nibh dapibus nec. Nulla egestas purus ac finibus semper. Integer tristique, leo in sagittis iaculis, ligula justo dignissim dui, convallis congue enim est ac tellus.
</p>

<div style="background-color:#eeeeff;" id="focus-message" tabindex="1">
  <strong>This is the foucs div I want.</strong> I need to get jQuery to focus here upon reload.
</div>
```

Comment: Nice presentation, hardly get to see this

Comment: you missed the id selector and parenthesis on focus to actually execute it, try with $("#focus-message").focus();

Comment: agree, you're missing those elements

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti : OMG I had been wasting so much time and energy on this. Sometimes the solution is so aparent but you miss it :o Thanks a ton!

Comment: yeah at least your question was presented elegantly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes you miss the things right in-front of you, or so they say

Like Sudhir mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181748/tabindex-attribute-on-div-did-not-solve-focus?noredirect=1#comment75377402_44181748), I missed the id selector and parenthesis.

### Given below, is the updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#focus-message").focus()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Nam in justo eros. Praesent blandit venenatis sollicitudin. Donec vitae laoreet sem, at aliquam ligula. Morbi aliquet congue augue, ut vehicula neque semper quis. Fusce est ante, pellentesque a sollicitudin non, egestas ut dolor. In sit amet lorem vitae
  tellus mollis lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Duis cursus consectetur enim et dapibus. Suspendisse urna justo, placerat finibus venenatis et, mattis at odio. Aliquam pellentesque, sem gravida convallis ornare, libero sapien blandit turpis, ut laoreet
  sapien mi ut lorem. Vestibulum ornare sit amet tellus sit amet aliquet. Curabitur mauris sapien, vestibulum ac auctor ut, consequat vel massa. Vivamus sit amet mauris fermentum, laoreet sapien in, mattis elit. In tincidunt, mi at ullamcorper lacinia,
  lectus tellus convallis felis, sit amet ultrices sapien nisi volutpat quam. Sed nec odio lacinia, tempor ligula at, ullamcorper ante. Phasellus eget vulputate purus.
</p>

<p>
  Nulla facilisi. Sed molestie lacus non ex ultricies, gravida gravida tortor porta. Nullam sed magna sed justo congue posuere commodo ut massa. Aliquam rhoncus nunc nulla, vitae commodo urna laoreet porta. Pellentesque eu tellus faucibus, rhoncus nunc
  sit amet, congue lectus. Praesent consectetur est nisi, finibus porttitor eros euismod ac. Integer ac magna a erat eleifend tempus. Quisque nec neque ullamcorper, volutpat est finibus, laoreet magna. Integer sit amet sodales justo. Sed accumsan dolor
  augue, at faucibus turpis pulvinar ac. Etiam sed lorem ligula.
</p>

<p>
  Quisque lobortis mattis nunc, mattis rutrum nisi sodales a. In iaculis consequat mauris, ac vulputate enim volutpat eget. Morbi vel nulla suscipit, fermentum leo id, sollicitudin quam. Etiam tincidunt libero turpis, ut consequat lorem consequat a. Nulla
  quam odio, molestie quis mauris eget, eleifend rhoncus nisi. Pellentesque vel vulputate nulla. Curabitur volutpat risus et felis facilisis venenatis. Sed at interdum nibh. Praesent rhoncus neque eros, quis placerat tellus laoreet vitae. Aliquam feugiat
  non ante quis porttitor. Duis eu libero cursus, molestie elit a, accumsan tellus. Ut in tincidunt metus, a aliquet magna. Nam vitae tellus sit amet erat varius suscipit. Integer dapibus consequat risus, a facilisis ex sodales ac.
</p>

<p>
  Integer sed ornare velit, ut maximus orci. Aliquam pellentesque nisl in lorem mollis ullamcorper. Mauris ullamcorper metus nec rhoncus laoreet. Proin dui ex, laoreet id sem at, hendrerit ornare magna. In varius dolor quis nibh semper gravida. Etiam ut
  magna ut ante blandit convallis et id nulla. Praesent sagittis nunc sit amet nunc tempor sagittis. Sed at sapien vitae neque rhoncus pretium. Morbi ultrices, ex id tincidunt placerat, ante arcu semper neque, vel consequat velit tellus eu leo. Nam convallis
  lorem fermentum auctor vestibulum.
</p>

<p>
  Morbi ac ante purus. In hendrerit commodo interdum. Mauris nec libero condimentum, pharetra nunc ac, viverra velit. Sed consequat erat sit amet ex aliquet semper. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc blandit neque eget mi faucibus, non placerat sapien mollis. Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent et massa sollicitudin, posuere velit vitae, convallis urna. In id turpis tellus. Nullam ligula mauris, blandit id facilisis in, hendrerit a sem. Vestibulum sodales vulputate est, non finibus
  quam scelerisque quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce sagittis dapibus eros, a finibus nunc vulputate vel. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
  ac turpis egestas.
</p>

<p>
  Duis ullamcorper justo et nulla placerat iaculis. Nunc dictum felis pulvinar tortor eleifend ullamcorper. Aliquam pretium, ipsum quis porttitor cursus, dolor dolor tincidunt libero, in tincidunt enim sem vitae dolor. Etiam ex mauris, ullamcorper a blandit
  in, placerat a orci. Curabitur purus ex, placerat eu condimentum a, interdum at diam. Donec dignissim nisl eget sapien blandit, molestie hendrerit tellus tristique. Fusce consectetur nisl pellentesque ullamcorper tincidunt. Ut pharetra eget nunc non
  consectetur. Curabitur consequat ut elit consequat consequat. Fusce imperdiet dui augue, ut lobortis mi consequat quis. Nulla tincidunt aliquet urna quis tempus. Integer sagittis magna sed maximus dapibus. Nam orci arcu, feugiat efficitur scelerisque
  et, pretium id sapien. Vestibulum finibus ultricies neque eget ultrices. Duis ornare leo condimentum felis iaculis, sit amet condimentum tortor feugiat. Quisque efficitur eros sem, ac consequat arcu placerat sit amet.
</p>

<p>
  Pellentesque arcu eros, aliquet a viverra ut, egestas a elit. Nulla lorem magna, volutpat vel consequat sed, ornare ut erat. Integer ullamcorper, sem et maximus sodales, sapien purus tempus quam, vel faucibus dolor risus viverra nulla. Integer suscipit
  arcu a nulla faucibus pellentesque. Donec id eleifend augue. Donec id luctus ante, non dapibus libero. Donec enim odio, mollis et rutrum sed, semper id tortor. Duis sed lacus felis. Sed dictum pulvinar orci in faucibus. Phasellus non varius erat, quis
  facilisis dui. Fusce non nunc ac lectus interdum consectetur. Nunc in suscipit mi. Aliquam interdum sapien non purus malesuada laoreet. Vestibulum a diam nec sapien commodo aliquam. Sed eget accumsan justo, consequat suscipit mauris.
</p>

<p>
  In finibus vel mi ac feugiat. In efficitur fermentum metus, vel porta massa molestie non. Ut vitae tortor ut urna dapibus fringilla. Nullam ornare placerat bibendum. Suspendisse et venenatis nisi. Cras tincidunt placerat erat id volutpat. Nunc sed eros
  eu lacus pulvinar bibendum vel id augue. Proin id lorem augue.
</p>

<p>
  Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In non est ullamcorper, congue ante non, mollis purus. Donec cursus posuere sagittis. Fusce rutrum vitae orci ut mollis. Nunc elementum lectus eu placerat vehicula. Morbi vitae efficitur libero.
  Vivamus suscipit malesuada erat ac tempor. Nulla ullamcorper tellus id hendrerit ullamcorper. Ut tellus nisl, tempus viverra porta in, vulputate non augue. Morbi aliquet neque eu neque scelerisque egestas. Nulla porta, leo nec ultricies hendrerit, lacus
  neque porttitor lorem, sed viverra erat purus vel est. Ut a purus et eros porttitor pellentesque. Donec ut ligula ornare lorem viverra condimentum ac feugiat ligula.
</p>

<p>
  Nulla purus metus, molestie vel ligula ut, ultricies tristique urna. Sed gravida nisi id iaculis porttitor. Sed id orci in ligula varius malesuada eu a enim. Proin ullamcorper sagittis imperdiet. Donec quis sodales tellus. Quisque volutpat ipsum quis
  accumsan tempor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris tempor efficitur risus, non rutrum ex aliquet ac.
</p>

<p>
  Aliquam arcu odio, tristique sit amet ex at, consequat suscipit dolor. Nunc efficitur mauris sit amet porttitor pellentesque. Aliquam auctor lorem eget mi laoreet tristique. Cras eros risus, dapibus non vestibulum eget, consectetur in est. Cras congue
  et justo quis varius. Morbi rhoncus condimentum dui, eget dapibus metus interdum id. Proin feugiat ligula vitae nulla porta porttitor. Donec sit amet vestibulum urna. Phasellus ornare ullamcorper lectus vitae aliquet. Nunc imperdiet turpis sapien, tristique
  accumsan tortor dignissim eu. Nunc dictum purus eu massa maximus fermentum. Fusce malesuada ullamcorper eros. Nullam in urna et ex aliquam tincidunt.
</p>

<p>
  Proin faucibus condimentum eleifend. Suspendisse sed felis nec nisl convallis eleifend. Ut a lorem et mi dignissim accumsan in in magna. Nulla eget consequat mauris. Phasellus odio ex, tincidunt non elit ac, commodo mollis quam. Etiam tempor sem ut nunc
  faucibus molestie. Mauris commodo mauris mi, at dapibus neque consectetur sed.
</p>

<p>
  Vivamus at lobortis augue, quis accumsan ex. Phasellus nec pulvinar eros, at consectetur urna. Fusce id lacinia dolor. Curabitur auctor metus dui, non fringilla mauris consectetur nec. Nulla aliquam orci et pretium euismod. Curabitur tristique consectetur
  finibus. Pellentesque condimentum sodales aliquet. Etiam augue augue, faucibus sed congue eu, volutpat elementum nunc. Donec imperdiet arcu vestibulum felis dignissim, at pretium leo volutpat. Quisque gravida purus nisl, sed pulvinar metus commodo quis.
</p>

<p>
  Morbi aliquet cursus elit, nec fermentum diam. Donec tortor nisl, gravida a lobortis nec, dictum sit amet elit. Nunc rhoncus sem a aliquet suscipit. Duis erat sem, efficitur volutpat facilisis non, aliquet vitae tellus. Sed ex elit, ullamcorper a dolor
  quis, mollis sodales dolor. Aenean bibendum leo augue, a pretium ante maximus nec. Phasellus nec risus at nisi laoreet hendrerit nec eu tellus. Phasellus euismod sollicitudin est vel ultricies. Cras suscipit elit orci.
</p>

<p>
  Nam quis dui aliquam, rutrum dolor id, commodo nisi. Mauris interdum eros ac odio pharetra efficitur sed et turpis. Quisque vitae erat orci. Sed ornare ultricies molestie. In gravida porta quam, ut iaculis nisl venenatis at. Sed elementum auctor suscipit.
  Vestibulum rutrum, lorem eu tristique suscipit, felis felis varius arcu, a vestibulum dolor mauris ut velit. Integer placerat urna id mauris sodales, mollis scelerisque felis consectetur. Proin fringilla lacus at molestie fringilla. Morbi vitae porta
  mauris. In ut leo ut metus pulvinar finibus. Pellentesque id mi quis enim porta interdum. Aliquam vulputate tristique lobortis. Vestibulum sollicitudin rhoncus nunc quis rhoncus.
</p>

<p>
  Etiam et enim rhoncus, euismod elit in, facilisis diam. Nulla vehicula dui nec ultrices vestibulum. Pellentesque tristique, mauris a euismod convallis, massa libero luctus massa, eu elementum enim mi quis lacus. Duis non sapien eget lectus pulvinar fringilla
  eu sit amet nibh. Nam porta lectus at nisl imperdiet ornare. Mauris eget quam interdum, congue magna nec, semper augue. Fusce erat orci, fermentum ut turpis sit amet, gravida blandit purus. Duis vel posuere lectus, id finibus neque. Fusce nec molestie
  odio, id rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt lectus ipsum, nec malesuada nibh dapibus nec. Nulla egestas purus ac finibus semper. Integer tristique, leo in sagittis iaculis, ligula justo dignissim dui, convallis congue enim est ac tellus.
</p>

<div style="background-color:#eeeeff;" id="focus-message" tabindex="1">
  <strong>This is the foucs div I want.</strong> I need to get jQuery to focus here upon reload.
</div>
```